# Javascript: Exporting browser's native undo/redo stacks for a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, undo

Is there any method to export/save any browser's native undo/redo stacks for a textarea? I would like to be able to undo/redo all typing in the textarea, after-the-fact.

I also wanted use javascript to call the native undo/redo stacks, which is easily done via:

```
$('#textarea_im_using').focus();
document.execCommand('undo', false, null);
```

But, this resulted in a NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure error message in the console. Any ideas why?

So in short I have two issues:

1. Export the native browser's undo stack
2. Call native browser's undo method.

I am currently using Mozilla Firefox (latest version). I am happy to try any browser that works (except Safari).

Comment: `execCommand` relates to `contentEditable` elements, not `textarea` elements. Do you *need* to use `textarea`? Or could you use a `contentEditable` `div` instead?

Comment: I need to be able to replay the typing of programming code. I was worried about using a contentEditable div because of all the tabs, and spacing issues. Looking into contentEditable divs now (not experienced with them).

Comment: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable appears to handle spacing fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`execCommand`, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand), relates to document design mode or `contentEditable` elements, rather than form fields like `textarea`.

Using a `contentEditable` `div` instead may let you do what you're trying to accomplish. Certainly, on browsers that support it, it lets you programmatically trigger an `undo` action, and I believe you have much more control over a `contentEditable` `div` than over a `textarea`.

[Live Example](http://codepen.io/tjcrowder/pen/txeCz):

HTML:

```
<p>Edit me:</p>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="buttonUndo">Undo</button>
```

CSS:

```
#editor {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 2em;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
var buttonUndo = document.getElementById("buttonUndo");
editor.contentEditable = true;
buttonUndo.onclick = function() {
  document.execCommand("undo", false, null);
};
```

*(Used `onclick` there because IE8 supports this stuff, and I didn't feel like playing the `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` game...)*

Comment: Thanks T.J. I have made the changes and now the error is removed! Nice catch. Do you have any knowledge of the second question -> how to export/save the browsers undo/redo stack?

Comment: @cgn: I don't. I suspect you can't, though. I don't think there's any standard in that area.